# How to hash a password with random salt?

Tags: php

Here is my code for hashing a password with random salt. But unfortunately, it doesn't want to work, it gives an incorrect password.

Part one of the script where the user encodes his credentials.

```
<?php
  echo "enter the username \n";
  $username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  echo "enter the password\n";
  $password = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  //connecting to database
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata","accounts");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $salt = time();
  $hashedPassword = sha1($password . $salt);
  echo "$hashedPassword";
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (username, salt, password)
    VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPassword','$salt')");
  mysqli_close($con)
?>
```

The second part of the script where the user enters his credentials.

```
<?php
  echo "enter the username \n";
  $username = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  echo "enter the password\n";
  $password = trim(fgets(STDIN));
  //connecting to database
  $db = mysql_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata") or die(mysql_error());
  //selecting our database
  $db_select = mysql_select_db("accounts", $db) or die(mysql_error());
  $result= mysql_query("select * from login where username = '$username' ");
  if ( !$result ) exit("$userName wasn't found in the database!");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $storedPassword = $row['password'];
  $salt = $row['salt'];
  $hashedPassword = sha1($password . $salt);
  if ( $storedPassword != $hashedPassword ) {
    exit( 'incorrect password!' );
  } else {
    echo "ok";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're storing the salt in the `password` column, and vice-versa.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (username, salt, password)
   VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPassword','$salt')");
```

Changes this to:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (username, password, salt)
   VALUES ('$username', '$hashedPassword','$salt')");
```